# Create project without Counter Project template

Tags: android-studio, flutter

Could I create a flutter project without that "Counter" project that I have to delete every time?

Answer (score 2):

Currently this is not supported.

Please follow and upvote the associated [Github Issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15279).